# Calendar with mysql events and event details in table

Tags: php, html, mysql

I bring you the following question, I have this code which queries for the events by date and shows them in a basic html list below:

(display.php is opened and the desired date is selected with a jquery datepicker and then below it displays a list with all the events on that date)

display.php:

[HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/ufcnpyjs/1/)

```
<?Php

echo "<meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=windows-1252\">
<html>
<head>
<title>Demo of  three linked dropdown list showing country, state  jquery color animation by changing background color effects</title>
<META NAME=\"DESCRIPTION\" CONTENT=\"Demo of jquery background color animation on button click\">
<META NAME=\"KEYWORDS\" CONTENT=\"Demo color animation, background color animation, color of background, jquery animation\">

";
require "head.php";

echo "<style >
.na_dates {
    background-color: Green !important;
    background-image :none !important;
    color: #ffffff !important;
}
</style></head><body>";

require "config.php"; // Database Connection 

?>

Date: <input type="text" id="date_picker">
<br><br><br>
<div id=d1></div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

/////////////////////
function checkDate(selectedDate) {
<?Php

$q="select distinct date_format( fechaev_pros, '%d-%m-%Y' ) as date from prospectos";

$str="[ ";
foreach ($dbo->query($q) as $row) {
$str.="\"$row[date]\",";
}
$str=substr($str,0,(strlen($str)-1));
$str.="]";
echo "var not_available_dates=$str"; // array is created in JavaScript 

?>  
// var not_available_dates = ["5-12-2015", "25-12-2015", "1-1-2016", "2-2-2017"];
//For month 09 should be written as 9 only, 5th of any month to be written as 5 only. 
// Try to get Month Part , date part and year part from the selected date.
 var m = selectedDate.getMonth()+1;
 var d = selectedDate.getDate();
 var y = selectedDate.getFullYear();
 m=m.toString();
 d=d.toString();
if(m.length <2){m='0'+m;} // Make the month 2 digit, Example 02 for Feb 
if(d.length <2){d='0'+d;} // Make the date 2 digit , example 08 for 8th day of the month 
 // Create  a variable in dd-mm-yyyy format ( or the format you want ) 
 // In JavaScript January month starts with 0 and December is 11 so we will increment the month count by 1 
 var date_to_check = d+ '-' + m + '-'  + y ;
 //alert(date_to_check);
  // Loop through all the elements of Not avalable dates array ///
 for (var i = 0; i < not_available_dates.length; i++) {
 
 // Now check if the selected  date is inside the not available  dates array. 
 if ($.inArray(date_to_check, not_available_dates) != -1 ) {
 return [true,' ','Open date T'];
 }else{
return [false,'na_dates','Close date F'];
}// end of if else 
} // end of for loop
} // end of function checkDate
////////
$(function() {
    $( "#date_picker" ).datepicker({
dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
beforeShowDay:checkDate,
onSelect:function() {
selectedDate = $('#date_picker').val();
var url="display-data.php?selectedDate="+selectedDate;
$('#d1').load(url);
  }
});
});
//////////////////////////
/////////////
})
</script>

<?Php
require "footer.php";
?>
</body>
</html>
```

display-data.php:

[HERE2](https://jsfiddle.net/hLx7wknu/1/)

```
require "config.php"; // Database Connection 
$date=$_GET['selectedDate'];
$date = new DateTime($date);
$date=$date->format('Y-m-d');

//echo $date;
$sql="select * from prospectos where fechaev_pros ='$date'";

foreach ($dbo->query($sql) as $row) {
echo "$row[fechaev_pros]: $row[nombre_pros]<br>";
}
?>
```

So, my question is: how do I make this list (which is working very well according to the created query)
1.Show the list in a table
2.Show a calendar below by default with the week and events marked by day

I have tried to use jQuery full calendar without much success really. 
So I was opting to create a basic HTML calendar and table

Comment: Using something like fullcalendar will be a lot less effort unless you have some very unusual requirements. It's unclear what difficulties you had with it. (P.s. fullcalendar has nothing to do with jquery)

Answer (score 0):

mysqldb tabe data

```
CREATE TABLE `events` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `date` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `event` text,
  `remarks` text
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
-- Dumping data for table `events`
--

INSERT INTO `events` (`id`, `date`, `event`, `remarks`) VALUES
(1, '2023-01-01', 'New Year', ''),
(2, '2023-01-14', 'Shankaranti', ''),
(3, '2023-01-15', 'Event three', ''),
(4, '2023-01-20', 'Event Four', '');

--
-- Indexes for dumped tables
--

--
-- Indexes for table `events`
--
ALTER TABLE `events`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for dumped tables
--

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for table `events`
--
ALTER TABLE `events`
  MODIFY `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=5;
COMMIT;
```

dbconnect.php

```
<?php
class dbcon
{
    private $dcon=false;
    
    //Mysqli Connection Open
    function __construct($db)
    {
        $this->con($db);
    }
    
    //Mysqli Connection Close
    function __destruct()
    {
        mysqli_close($this->dcon);
    }
    
    //Database Details
    private function con($db)
    {
        $host = $db["server"];
        $username = $db["username"];
        $password = $db["password"];
        $database = $db["database"];
        
        $con = mysqli_connect($host,$username,$password,$database);
        if($con)
            {
                $this->dcon = $con;
            }
        else
            {
                echo "Server or Database Connection Error!";
            }
    }
    public function query($query,$error)
    {
        $con = $this->dcon;
        $run_query = mysqli_query($con,$query);
        if($run_query)
        {
            return $run_query;
        }
        else
        {
            $error=array("result"=>"error","message"=>mysqli_error($con));
            return $error;
        }   
    }
    public function querydata($querystring,$error)
    {
        $query = $this->query($querystring,$error);
        
        if(isset($query->num_rows)>0)
                {
                    $dat=array();
                    while($data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query))
                    {
                        $dat[]=$data;
                    }
                    return $dat;
                }
                else
                {
                    echo "Check the query once! <hr/>".$query['message']." <hr/>";
                }
    }
}
$db=array("server"=>"127.0.0.1","username"=>"root","password"=>"manju!@#123","database"=>"images");
    $con = new dbcon($db);
?>
```

eventlist.php

```
<?php
require_once "dbconnect.php";
if(isset($_POST['getlist']))
{
    $date = $_POST['date'];
    
    $data = $con->querydata("select * from events where date='".$date."'","error");
    if(is_array($data))
    {
        $datacount=count($data);
        if($datacount>0)
        {
            for($i=0;$i<$datacount;$i+=1)
            {
                echo "Event on this date ".$date." : ".$data[$i]["event"];
            }
        }else
        {
            echo "No Event on this $date;";
        }
    }
    else
    {
        echo $data;
    }
}
?>
```

eventsbydate.php Request string http://localhost/eventsbydate.php?date=2023-01-01

```
<?php require_once "dbconnect.php";
function din($s,$d,$in,$fr)
        { 
            return date($s,strtotime($d." + ".$in." ".$fr));
        }
        $date = (isset($_REQUEST['date']))?$_REQUEST['date']:date("Y-m-1");
        $dy = din("Y",$date,"0","days");
        $dm = din("m",$date,"0","days");
        $dM = din("M",$date,"0","days"); 
        $dye = din("Y-m",$date,"0","days");     
?>
Date: <input type="date" id="date_picker" />
<hr/>
<div id="d1"></div>
<h2>Events on <?=$dM?> - <?=$dy?></h2>
<div class="dlist" style="padding:20px; float:left; width:40%">
    <?php
        
        $events =  $con->querydata("select * from events where date like '%".$dye."%' order by  date desc","error");
        if(is_array($events))
        {
            $datacount=count($events);
            if($datacount>0)
            {
                ?><table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5" border="1">
                <tr>
                    <td>Date</td>
                    <td>Event</td>
                    <td>Remarks</td>
                </tr>
                
                <?php
                for($i=0;$i<$datacount;$i+=1)
                {
                    ?><tr><?php
                        ?><td><?=$events[$i]["date"]?></td><?php
                        ?><td><?=$events[$i]["event"]?></td><?php
                        ?><td><?=$events[$i]["remarks"]?></td><?php
                    ?></tr><?php
                }
                ?></table><?php
            }else
            {
                echo "No Event on this $date;";
            }
        }
        else
        {
            echo $events;
        }
    ?>
</div>
<div id="calendar" style="float:right; padding:20px;  width:50%">
    <?php
        
    ?>
    <div class="head">
        <b><?=$dM?></b> : <b><?=$dy?></b>
    </div>
    <div class="days">
    <?php       
        $days = cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN, $dm, $dy);
        $sytl="";$event="";
        for($i=0;$i<$days;$i+=1)
        {
            $day = din("d-D",$date,$i,'days');
            $edate = din("Y-m-d",$date,$i,'days');
            $did = din("Ymd",$date,$i,'days');
            $devent = $con->querydata("select * from events where date = '".$edate."' order by  date desc","error");
            //var_dump($devent);
            if(is_array($devent)){
                    if(count($devent)>0)
                    {
                        $sytl="#ccc";
                        $event=$devent[0]['event'];
                    }else
                    {
                        $sytl="#fff";
                        $event="";

                    }
                }else{
                    $sytl="#fff";
                    $event="";
                }if($i % 6==0){?><br style="clear:both" /><?php }else{}
            ?><div class="day" style="width:10%; text-align:center;background:<?=$sytl?>;float:left;padding:10px;border:1px solid #999;margin:4px;">
                <?php echo $day;?><hr/>
                <?=$event?>
            </div><?php
            
        }
    ?>
    </div>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(function() {
        $("#date_picker").change(function(){
                date = $(this).val();
                $("#d1").html("getting data...");
                $("#d1").load("eventlist.php",{'getlist':'get','date':date},function(d){$("#d1").html(d);});
            });
        
        
});
</script>
```

Comment: thank u for your help....its works but isnt quite what im looking for